# Prevent movement of hands on push up animation

Tags: animation

I made a push up animation with a human character and its hands are moving down and upwards. Can I somehow fix the position of the hands? I mean in a way not to be able to move/rotate it.

My problem is something like the push up part in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-r7mWDgQbmU

Comment: So you are using an armature? You need to use inverse kinematics constraints. Search for tutorials about that. Here is one to get you started https://youtu.be/DZ_ocmY8xEI

Answer (score 1):

Here's the simplest version of an arm rig:

- **upper arm**, **lower arm** and **hand** are one connected chain
- **upper arm** is parented to **body** with offset
- **hand** has a Copy Rotation Constraint to **hand target**. Both bones have the same rotation. Using hand instead of **hand target** prevents the hand from getting torn apart when you accidentally move **hand target** too far away.
- **lower arm** has an IK constraint to **hand target**, chain length 2. That means blender will rotate **lower arm** and **upper arm** to somehow reach **hand target**.
- **upper arm**, **lower arm** and **hand** are deforming the character mesh while **hand target** is exclusively for animation.

If you want to animate the arm, move **hand target**. If you want to do pushups, move **body**. The arm takes care of itself.

Such rigs can become much more complex, and be it just to have control over the elbow. But the principle is usually similar.

[image: up and down and up and down]